# Safari pdf URL download showing "404 not found" in Swift why?

Tags: swift, url, download, safari

I am using safari do download files

Code:

```
@IBAction func downloadCVbtn(_ sender: Any) {
    
    let file = candidateProfileData?.result?.user?.resume
    let resumeStr = "https://test.com/test/storage/app/resume/" + file!
    let url = URL(string: resumeStr)
    UIApplication.shared.open(url!)
}
```

o/p: **here file is downloading but in page showing 404 not found** why?

[Safari Output screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pU0rU.png)

could you please guide me

Answer (score 0):

There is a high possibility that the URL is `nil`.

There are many reasons to be `nil`.

Try this..

```
let resumeStr = "https://test.com/test/storage/app/resume/" + file!
guard let encodedStr = resumeStr.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed) else { return }

let url = URL(string: encodedStr)!
print(url.absoluteString)
```